# getSheetByName not working on setActiveSpreadsheet, but working on getActiveSpreadsheet in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code. It doesn't seem to work with setActiveSpreadsheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Id')
var booleanRange = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss).getSheetByName("Sheet1")
```

but works with getActiveSpreadsheet

```
var booleanRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null (line 4, file "Code")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setActiveSpreadsheet() sets the active spreadsheet but does not return that spreadsheet.

Instead, try

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Id')
var booleanRange = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 1):

`SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss)` is a **void** function, meaning that it **does not** provide a result value to its caller (see image attached). Therefore you **can not** apply a method on it.

You can only run it like that and it will set spreadsheet **ss** as the active spreadsheet:

```
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
```

[image: Further explanation]

> **References:**

[setActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivespreadsheetnewactivespreadsheet)